# Reset visited links in UIWebView, iOS 5

Tags: javascript, css, ios, uiwebview

in iOS 5, UIWebView renders visited links in a different color. It seems UIWebView maintains a list of visited links so they can be rendered differently. How to clean up such a list? That is, all the links will be rendered in the same way?

It seems not related to cache and cookies. I tried the following and it does not work:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```css
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color: blue; }​
```